# Embedding Youtube video in Android tablet webview

Tags: php, android, youtube

I have made one website in php(CakePHP Framework) and had made its apk to run it on tablet as webview ,on clicking Youtube video redirecting me out of application ,code I have used is as below:

`<object width="311" height="176">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $video['Video']['video_key'];?>"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $video['Video']['video_key'];?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  width="891" height="609"></embed></object>`

can any one help me to run this embeded code ?

Comment: I have tried with iframe,embeded code ,Video.js but nothing is working in tablet of anroid

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: I have tried with iframe,embeded code ,Video.js but nothing is working in tablet of anroid

Comment: @Jhanvi what exactly your are getting its redirecting or not playing

Comment: if i am putting iframe its not running and if putting embeded code its redirecting me ....same thing is wrking with browser but only not wrking in webview...

Comment: @Jhanvi k...did you add Webviewclient

Comment: on anroid side all supports has been provided....and obviously apk is made to run a website as webview it can be done by vebVidewClioent class extending is it right?